# Error connecting to DB2 with python/SQLAlchemy: "0x0000" Parameter value "0x0000" is not supported. SQLSTATE=58017

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, db2

I'm trying to connect to a db2 database via SQLAlchemy using the following script:  (Windows 7 x64, Python 3.6 using libraries: ibm_db_sa, and ibm_db_2.0.8a, DB2 on z/OS)

```
import traceback
import ibm_db_sa
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.automap import automap_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        Base = automap_base()
        connection_string = 'db2+ibm_db://userName:Password@Server.com:6001/DB_0;'
        engine = create_engine(connection_string)
        session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autocommit=False,
                                              autoflush=False,
                                              bind=engine))
        # reflect the tables
        Base.prepare(engine, reflect=True)
        base_sa = Base.classes

    except Exception as err:
        print(traceback.format_exc())
        engine.close()
```

Unfortunately I'm getting the below traceback/error on the **Base.prepare(engine, reflect=True) line**.  This is a proof of concept code to test if I can indeed connect to a db2 database and reflect tables using SQLAlchemy.

I have also tried to run a raw SQL statement instead of reflecting that has had the same outcome:

```
result = engine.execute(r'SELECT * FROM fooschema.footable;')
```

TRACEBACK:

```
Connected to pydev debugger (build 171.4694.67)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\1234567890\Documents\cool_app\.env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 1122, in _do_get
    return self._pool.get(wait, self._timeout)
  File "C:\Users\1234567890\Documents\cool_app\.env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\queue.py", line 145, in get
    raise Empty
sqlalchemy.util.queue.Empty

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\1234567890\Documents\cool_app\.env\lib\site-packages\ibm_db_dbi.py", line 592, in connect
    conn = ibm_db.connect(dsn, '', '', conn_options)
 SQLCODE=-30073

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\1234567890\Documents\cool_app\.env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2147, in _wrap_pool_connect
    return fn()
  File "C:\Users\1234567890\Documents\cool_app\.env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 328, in unique_connection
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
  File "C:\Users\1234567890\Documents\cool_app\.env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 766, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
  File "C:\Users\1234567890\Documents\cool_app\.env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 516, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
  File "C:\Users\1234567890\Documents\cool_app\.env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 1138, in _do_get
    self._dec_overflow()
  File "C:\Users\1234567890\Documents\cool_app\.env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 66, in __exit__
    compat.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb)
  File "C:\Users\1234567890\Documents\cool_app\.env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 187, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\1234567890\Documents\cool_app\.env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 1135, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
  File "C:\Users\1234567890\Documents\cool_app\.env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 333, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "C:\Users\1234567890\Documents\cool_app\.env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 461, in __init__
    self.__connect(first_connect_check=True)
  File "C:\Users\1234567890\Documents\cool_app\.env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 651, in __connect
    connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
  File "C:\Users\1234567890\Documents\cool_app\.env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\strategies.py", line 105, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "C:\Users\1234567890\Documents\cool_app\.env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 393, in connect
    return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "C:\Users\1234567890\Documents\cool_app\.env\lib\site-packages\ibm_db_dbi.py", line 595, in connect
    raise _get_exception(inst)
ibm_db_dbi.ProgrammingError: ibm_db_dbi::ProgrammingError: [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL30073N  "0x0000" Parameter value "0x0000" is not supported.  SQLSTATE=58017\r SQLCODE=-30073

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/1234567890/Documents/cool_app/db2_is_working.py", line 18, in <module>
    Base.prepare(engine, reflect=True)
  File "C:\Users\1234567890\Documents\cool_app\.env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\ext\automap.py", line 753, in prepare
    autoload_replace=False
  File "C:\Users\1234567890\Documents\cool_app\.env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\schema.py", line 3840, in reflect
    with bind.connect() as conn:
  File "C:\Users\1234567890\Documents\cool_app\.env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2091, in connect
    return self._connection_cls(self, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\1234567890\Documents\cool_app\.env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 90, in __init__
    if connection is not None else engine.raw_connection()
  File "C:\Users\1234567890\Documents\cool_app\.env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2177, in raw_connection
    self.pool.unique_connection, _connection)
  File "C:\Users\1234567890\Documents\cool_app\.env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2151, in _wrap_pool_connect
    e, dialect, self)
  File "C:\Users\1234567890\Documents\cool_app\.env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1465, in _handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection
    exc_info
  File "C:\Users\1234567890\Documents\cool_app\.env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 203, in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)
  File "C:\Users\1234567890\Documents\cool_app\.env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 186, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\1234567890\Documents\cool_app\.env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2147, in _wrap_pool_connect
    return fn()
  File "C:\Users\1234567890\Documents\cool_app\.env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 328, in unique_connection
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
  File "C:\Users\1234567890\Documents\cool_app\.env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 766, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
  File "C:\Users\1234567890\Documents\cool_app\.env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 516, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
  File "C:\Users\1234567890\Documents\cool_app\.env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 1138, in _do_get
    self._dec_overflow()
  File "C:\Users\1234567890\Documents\cool_app\.env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 66, in __exit__
    compat.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb)
  File "C:\Users\1234567890\Documents\cool_app\.env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 187, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\1234567890\Documents\cool_app\.env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 1135, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
  File "C:\Users\1234567890\Documents\cool_app\.env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 333, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "C:\Users\1234567890\Documents\cool_app\.env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 461, in __init__
    self.__connect(first_connect_check=True)
  File "C:\Users\1234567890\Documents\cool_app\.env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 651, in __connect
    connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
  File "C:\Users\1234567890\Documents\cool_app\.env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\strategies.py", line 105, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "C:\Users\1234567890\Documents\cool_app\.env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 393, in connect
    return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "C:\Users\1234567890\Documents\cool_app\.env\lib\site-packages\ibm_db_dbi.py", line 595, in connect
    raise _get_exception(inst)
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (ibm_db_dbi.ProgrammingError) ibm_db_dbi::ProgrammingError: [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL30073N  "0x0000" Parameter value "0x0000" is not supported.  SQLSTATE=58017\r SQLCODE=-30073

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\1234567890\Documents\cool_app\.env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 1122, in _do_get
    return self._pool.get(wait, self._timeout)
  File "C:\Users\1234567890\Documents\cool_app\.env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\queue.py", line 145, in get
    raise Empty
sqlalchemy.util.queue.Empty

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\1234567890\Documents\cool_app\.env\lib\site-packages\ibm_db_dbi.py", line 592, in connect
    conn = ibm_db.connect(dsn, '', '', conn_options)
 SQLCODE=-30073

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\1234567890\Documents\cool_app\.env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2147, in _wrap_pool_connect
    return fn()
  File "C:\Users\1234567890\Documents\cool_app\.env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 328, in unique_connection
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
  File "C:\Users\1234567890\Documents\cool_app\.env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 766, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
  File "C:\Users\1234567890\Documents\cool_app\.env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 516, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
  File "C:\Users\1234567890\Documents\cool_app\.env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 1138, in _do_get
    self._dec_overflow()
  File "C:\Users\1234567890\Documents\cool_app\.env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 66, in __exit__
    compat.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb)
  File "C:\Users\1234567890\Documents\cool_app\.env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 187, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\1234567890\Documents\cool_app\.env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 1135, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
  File "C:\Users\1234567890\Documents\cool_app\.env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 333, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "C:\Users\1234567890\Documents\cool_app\.env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 461, in __init__
    self.__connect(first_connect_check=True)
  File "C:\Users\1234567890\Documents\cool_app\.env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 651, in __connect
    connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
  File "C:\Users\1234567890\Documents\cool_app\.env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\strategies.py", line 105, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "C:\Users\1234567890\Documents\cool_app\.env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 393, in connect
    return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "C:\Users\1234567890\Documents\cool_app\.env\lib\site-packages\ibm_db_dbi.py", line 595, in connect
    raise _get_exception(inst)
ibm_db_dbi.ProgrammingError: ibm_db_dbi::ProgrammingError: [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL30073N  "0x0000" Parameter value "0x0000" is not supported.  SQLSTATE=58017\r SQLCODE=-30073

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/1234567890/Documents/cool_app/db2_is_working.py", line 18, in <module>
    Base.prepare(engine, reflect=True)
  File "C:\Users\1234567890\Documents\cool_app\.env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\ext\automap.py", line 753, in prepare
    autoload_replace=False
  File "C:\Users\1234567890\Documents\cool_app\.env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\schema.py", line 3840, in reflect
    with bind.connect() as conn:
  File "C:\Users\1234567890\Documents\cool_app\.env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2091, in connect
    return self._connection_cls(self, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\1234567890\Documents\cool_app\.env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 90, in __init__
    if connection is not None else engine.raw_connection()
  File "C:\Users\1234567890\Documents\cool_app\.env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2177, in raw_connection
    self.pool.unique_connection, _connection)
  File "C:\Users\1234567890\Documents\cool_app\.env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2151, in _wrap_pool_connect
    e, dialect, self)
  File "C:\Users\1234567890\Documents\cool_app\.env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1465, in _handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection
    exc_info
  File "C:\Users\1234567890\Documents\cool_app\.env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 203, in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)
  File "C:\Users\1234567890\Documents\cool_app\.env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 186, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\1234567890\Documents\cool_app\.env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2147, in _wrap_pool_connect
    return fn()
  File "C:\Users\1234567890\Documents\cool_app\.env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 328, in unique_connection
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
  File "C:\Users\1234567890\Documents\cool_app\.env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 766, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
  File "C:\Users\1234567890\Documents\cool_app\.env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 516, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
  File "C:\Users\1234567890\Documents\cool_app\.env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 1138, in _do_get
    self._dec_overflow()
  File "C:\Users\1234567890\Documents\cool_app\.env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 66, in __exit__
    compat.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb)
  File "C:\Users\1234567890\Documents\cool_app\.env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 187, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\1234567890\Documents\cool_app\.env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 1135, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
  File "C:\Users\1234567890\Documents\cool_app\.env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 333, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "C:\Users\1234567890\Documents\cool_app\.env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 461, in __init__
    self.__connect(first_connect_check=True)
  File "C:\Users\1234567890\Documents\cool_app\.env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 651, in __connect
    connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
  File "C:\Users\1234567890\Documents\cool_app\.env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\strategies.py", line 105, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "C:\Users\1234567890\Documents\cool_app\.env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 393, in connect
    return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "C:\Users\1234567890\Documents\cool_app\.env\lib\site-packages\ibm_db_dbi.py", line 595, in connect
    raise _get_exception(inst)
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (ibm_db_dbi.ProgrammingError) ibm_db_dbi::ProgrammingError: [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL30073N  "0x0000" Parameter value "0x0000" is not supported.  SQLSTATE=58017\r SQLCODE=-30073

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\1234567890\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharm 2017.1.4\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1591, in <module>
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "C:\Users\1234567890\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharm 2017.1.4\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1018, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Users\1234567890\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharm 2017.1.4\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Users/1234567890/Documents/cool_app/db2_is_working.py", line 23, in <module>
    engine.close()
AttributeError: 'Engine' object has no attribute 'close'
```

Comment: Does the ibm_db_sa  sanity check work for you?  I mean the one in the Knowledge Center of Db2 LUW that uses the following format for the connection? `try:
    db2 = sqlalchemy.create_engine('ibm_db_sa://'+ db_user + ':' + db_pwd + '@db2_server_hostname:'+db2_port_number+'/' + db_name )

`

Comment: I get exactly the same error when I try the sanity check.    Mind you the create_engine line doesn't throw the error.  The error is thrown when I try to query a table or reflect the tables.

Comment: If i recall correctly, it uses lazy-connect. Do the MetaData() , and .bind, .create_all methods work as per IBM sample?

Comment: For information, I tried your revised script fragment, and it works for me with a trivial Db2 LUW database. However, it aborts with the SAMPLE database with a known issue in SQLAlchemy . Can you try with a different very simple database, in case you are experiencing another SQLAlchemy issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I didn't have the correct host/user/password.  I resolved the issue by creating a DSN, testing the connection and then using pyodbc to connect.  I still haven't been able to get SQLAlchemy to work with the connection but will post a separate question for that.

Update:  DB2 on z/OS is currently not supported by SQLAlchemy.

Answer (score 0):

As of Aug, 2020 SqlAlchemy supports IBM_db and I am able to successfully connect and retrieve data on Z/OS

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, MetaData
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine("db2+ibm_db://userId:password@host:port/db") #create a database engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
metadata = MetaData(schema='schemaName')
Base = declarative_base(bind=engine, metadata=metadata)

class Customers(Base):
   __tablename__ = 'tableName'
   CLIENT_ID = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
   CLIENT_NAME = Column(Integer)
   CREATED_BY = Column(String)

from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
Session = sessionmaker(bind = engine)
session = Session()
result = session.query(Customers).limit(2)

for row in result:
   print (row.CLIENT_NAME )
```